# Evaluating the limit of a polynomial fraction as the base goes to infinity where the polynomial orders are related

Tags: limits, solution-verification, proof-writing, logarithms, asymptotics

I am attempting to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^a}{x^b}$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers such that $a < b$.

It seems intuitive that this limit should evaluate to $0$, as:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} a\log x - b \log x \leq 0$$

Because $a < b$.

I worry-- because it's been a while since I've proven anything mathematically-- that this isn't a rigorous/correct proof, and wonder if anyone would be kind enough to point me in the right direction if I am on the wrong track?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$b-a>0 \implies \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^a}{x^b}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x^{b-a}}=0$$

Comment: I see what you did there. That's very good-- thank you!